# How to batch-rename photos from EXIF data?

Tags: photos, batch-rename, exif

I have a `DCIM` directory containing photos named as `IMG_{NNNN}.JPG` from iPhone and photos named as `DSC_{NNNN}.JPG` from Xperia.
This directory is the result of multiple directories merging, which all had different photos with same names (eg iPhone 3GS' `.../DCIM/IMG_0001.JPG`, iPhone 4S' `.../DCIM/IMG_0001.JPG` and iPhone 5s' `.../IMG_0001.JPG` different photos or Xperia Z3+'s before restore `.../DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0001.JPG` and Xperia Z3+'s after restore `.../DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0001.JPG` different photos). To rename photos so none went overwritten by another, I searched 'holes' in the list (eg if `PIC10.JPG` has been deleted since but `PIC9.JPG` and `PIC11.JPG` are still here, I have a hole so I can rename the second `PIC1.JPG` to `PIC10.JPG` so I don't lose it and don't end up with a messy directory containing files looking like doubles by the name).

I want to keep the current nomenclature for photos such as iPhone photos in `IMG_{NNNN}.JPG` and Xperia photos in `DSC_{NNNN}.JPG`.

I want to rename the photos in the order they were taken from the EXIF data (eg if the above example's `PIC1-2.JPG` that went `PIC10.JPG` has been shot before `PIC1.JPG` then this `PIC10.JPG` becomes `PIC1.JPG` and all subsequent photos are renamed as `PIC{N+1}.JPG`, or `PIC{N+X}.JPG` if x photos come at the list's beginning) — putting exifless photos first (ie the first exifless photo found becomes `PIC1.JPG`, the second becomes `PIC2.JPG` etc).

I do not want to rename the photos otherly than with their initial nomenclature (ie no `{ Date } iPhone photo.jpg` or `Xperia photo from { Date }.jpeg`).

Is there any way to do this simply? I'd rather get a command line way to do this, but even an Automator script or combined approach (eg an Automator script calling a shell script) will do just fine — as long as once the thing starts running, I don't have to touch the keyboard until the job's done.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use Python. Try [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/meaniruth/9d1d7f4a89534f67970c/raw/2cc81abc6bd0375eef29828cecf7e1d1c51cc8bf/rename_images.py) script.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @MichaelD Unfortunately, the script renames as `date[8:10] + '-' + date[5:7] + '-' + date[:4] + image_format`. I think it needs conditions to only increase the four digits number by one from the older to the newer, but I'm not sure about how to write that. Thanks though.

Comment: @DavidPostill Hello. I haven't tried any script [except Michael D.'s link's] so far as I could not find a script that does what I want it to do. I guess you imply that this post belongs to Stack Overflow, sorry for the wrong place.

Comment: @kvpb Wherever you post we expect some effort. It would also get closed on [so] for lack of effort.

Comment: @DavidPostill Which lack of effort? The lack of effort of not recalling how to write that kind of code and not having the time to search about that until I solve it? Writing this reminds me that if I was to do this, I simply wouldn't have asked anything at all and would have written it myself instead. My post is clear, written to be understood ('I have these pieces of the puzzle; I want the puzzle solved as close as that as possible'). My post isn't less detailed than most posts you answered to, so with all due respect, I'll ask you to keep that kind of misplaced commentary for yourself, sir.

Comment: @kvpb "Which lack of effort?" See above. "Super User is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems." Please remember that we are volunteers here, answering questions in our own time and for free. If you don't have time to at least try and write a script or to do any research then you should employ someone to do the work.

Comment: @kvpb The same goes for [so]. If you ask your question there they will give exactly the same response.

Comment: @DavidPostill That SuperUser isn't the right community to post this to, I understood — once is enough. Now, your commentary explaining point by point what doesn't fit, I can answer to you more constructively. I didn't mention what I tried as I simply could not find [after research on Google, GitHub, BitBucket etc] or write [just not having the time] anything suiting the need. I know people here are volunteers [rewarded with reputation points, may I highlight], which includes not being obligated to help at all. I ask for help; if someone helps I thank as I can, if no one helps too bad for me.

Comment: @DavidPostill It depends on the answerer much, while I have seen it happen on Stack Overflow. But then I just wouldn't know what to say or do, as someone asking for something with a post _that_ detailed clearly couldn't resolve things by themselves. Let me avoid mass judgments on speculations but take the problem the other way around by mentioning this: if people only answer when the answer has been found or only to correct something simple the original poster didn't see, those same people are limited to stated obvious as knowledge — thus Google search could do the same. :/

Comment: @DavidPostill Now, this not belonging here, I searched on Stack Overflow the day I read your first comment, and could not find anything suiting the need. As of today, I clearly understood that I'll have to find a Python manual and write this by myself — lacking time, I'll just stick with manual renaming of files for now. Have a good continuation. [Edit: To be sure, I reread my original post, which states 'a command line way' and not only 'a script', so I think this post might be relevant to both SuperUser and Stack Overflow.]